# PostgreSQL assertion/trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL:

```
Employee(id_employee, name, surname, section)
```

and

```
Section(id_section, manager)
```

section is a foreign key in "Employee" which refers to "Section" and manager is a foreign key in "Section" which refers to "Employee". I need an assertion with check or a trigger (better assertion with check) that every time I add a new section, checks that the manager (manager) that I add as foreign key, exists in the "Employee" table and the employee has the section (section) as foreign key for which he is the manager as the foreign key section.

In other words, I need that the employee who manage the section be also be an employee who works in that section.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want, but you need a trigger. As for ASSERTions, as the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSERT) states

> The ASSERT statement is a convenient shorthand for inserting debugging
>   checks into PL/pgSQL functions. ... Testing of assertions can be
>   enabled or disabled via the configuration parameter
>   plpgsql.check_asserts, which takes a Boolean value; the default is on.
>   If this parameter is off then ASSERT statements do nothing.
>
> Note that ASSERT is meant for detecting program bugs, not for
>   reporting ordinary error conditions. Use the RAISE statement,
>   described above, for that.

As for a CHECK constraint, you need to validate the value of a non-unique column in another table, that means a select. Unfortunately, check constraints cannot have selects.  

Further, you will need to be aware of insert sequence due to the the bi-directional nature of the FK. But that can be handled. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=158258a2eec6c7a25d9a3cf217928959) for complete example.

Comment: "*to be aware of insert sequence due to the the bi-directional nature of the FK*" - which can be handled by declaring the FKs as deferrable

Comment: True. I should have mentioned that. But auto-commit can defeat even that. Point being you still have to think about, not just put it on auto pilot.